# How do I call functions from a DLL in my resources?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, messagebox, loader

So I have this DLL and this other thing which I think is refered to as a Injector / loader? It basically loads my DLL into the process of itself so it takes my DLL and loads it into the process of "Injector.exe"
In the example down below it doesnt load it from resources but instead from the desktop, the same thing applies here.

Now sicne it's being loaded it doesnt really call any functions and this is where my problem comes in.

I would like to call some the Messagebox function when the DLL is being loaded.

As far as I know and the most logical way would be to do this in the `btnAssemblyLoad_Click` event so when the event happens it calls the functions in the DLL.
The issue is I have no idea what this would be called, I read something about "Reflection" but im not sure this is what I would need.

How should I go on about this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AssemblyLoader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tbAssemblyLocation.Text = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void btnAssemblyLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(tbAssemblyLocation.Text);
            Assembly.Load(an);
        }
    }
}
```

DLL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MSgBOxDllCS
{
    public class Funcs
    {
        public void CallMessageBox()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to call instance method of the non-static class, see below.

```
// Step 1: load assembly to memory
var an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(tbAssemblyLocation.Text);
var assembly = Assembly.Load(an);

// Step 2: get type from the assembly by name
var type = assembly.GetType("MSgBOxDllCS.Funcs");

// Step 3: get method of the type
var method = type.GetMethod("CallMessageBox");

// Step 4: create instance of the type
var funcs = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// Step 5: invoke the instance method
method.Invoke(funcs, null);
```

Generally speaking what you are building is called Plug-In Framework and there is plenty of examples on internet of how it can be done, you may be able to leverage existing frameworks too depending on your requirements.

Comment: That makes alot of sense! How ever it throws me this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"  on the method.Invoke, would this be because I need to have the dll in the resources?

Comment: Never mind! My bad on that one, So what the issue was, was that the example I showed you was with the old methodname, I had to change it in the loader! Everything is working perfectly!

Comment: Now I will go and read more about these classes and functions to fully understand whats going on when I write them all!

Comment: It does not throw an exception in my case. Your assembly with the code to run should reference all the required libraries though e.g. `System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: Sounds good! Reflection is very powerful concept to use, but it does come with the penalty on your performance, so caching of the loaded types is always a good idea.

Comment: "caching of the loaded types is always a good idea." What do you mean?

Comment: It is always a good idea to separate the concerns of retrieving the type information from querying it. Simple rule of thumb would be retrieve type once and use many times. Remember that reflection API is not doing it for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways how you can accomplish that.

1. Load an assembly, create an instance of a class, find the required method using Reflection and invoke it.

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(DllFilePath);
var funcs = assembly.CreateInstance("MSgBOxDllCS.Funcs");
var method = funcs.GetType().GetMethod("CallMessageBox");
method.Invoke(funcs, null);
```

2. The same but use a dynamic object, gives less control over reflected members but looks better:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(DllFilePath);
dynamic funcs = assembly.CreateInstance("MSgBOxDllCS.Funcs");
funcs.CallMessageBox();
```

3. And the last but not least, is to extract an interface and put it in a separate shared DLL. This approach would help to get rid of reflection calls and by it's nature is the most reliable:

Common shared DLL:

```
namespace Shared
{
   public interface IFuncs
   {
      void CallMessageBox();
   }
}
```

DLL to be loaded:

```
namespace MSgBOxDllCS
{
    public class Funcs : Shared.IFuncs
    {
        public void CallMessageBox()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Loader:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(DllFilePath);
var funcs = (Shared.IFuncs)assembly.CreateInstance("MSgBOxDllCS.Funcs");
funcs.CallMessageBox();
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you so much!